# Multiple OR in SQL statement with Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a question with Linq to Sql query in C#.

I have this query:

```
from A in context.General
                            join B in context.Applications on A.ID equals B.ID
                            from G in context.Notes
                            //where (G.CODE == A.NoteID || G.CODE == A.NoteID2 || G.CODE == A.NoteID3)
                            join X in context.Att on B.AttID equals X.AttID

 select new
                                {
                                    A.SomeStuff,
                                   B.SomeStuff
                                    G.NOTE_TEXT
                                });
```

My question is, which NOTE_TEXT the query will return, for example if in some case one record has three codes that match with the G.CODE field it will return three NOTE_TEXT or only the first one? Or in another case what happens if one record has only one match with the G.CODE field, and the others two has an empty value, only return that match or nothing?

Thank you so much, and please let me know if I'm not clear in my question.

Comment: The query will return as many rows as the rows that are matched with the query. If there is 3 rows that have a `G.Code` that you want it will return 3 rows.

Comment: Thanks, so if I have some record that has only one match (G.Code == A.NoteID1) and the others has an empty value in NoteID2 and NoteID3, it will return the entire row but only with the NOTE_TEXT from the first one?

Comment: Try it. We don't know your data.

Comment: The where will be run across each `G` so you will only get one `G` per `where` being `true`, regardless of why the `where` is true. Note however your query is doing `from`...`from` which means it is a cross-join from (A-B) x (G-X) so you will get an answer for every combination of them. (I.e. there is no relationship expressed between A-B and G-X to restrict G-X.